# How to access migration destinations that are not in the default view?

Tags: discussion, migration

I recently saw a question migrated from SO to AU. How is this sort of thing achieved, considering that AU doesn't appear here as an option:

[image]

Comment: Flag for moderator attention, if you see a good candidate for migration to AU.

Answer (score 4):

It was done by a diamond mod. Diamond mods can migrate to any Stack Exchange site.

If you feel that a particular question belongs on some other site Flag for Moderator Attention and mention `Belongs on x`